# How to access expired domain host from old DNS record?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, virtual-host, nameserver

I'm trying to access a website whose domain has just expired. The old IP address resolves to 206.225.92.33 which is the parent hosting company and not a dedicated address.

The domain name was registered to godaddy as identified by a WHOIS so it's possible that the website still exists even though the domain does not.

Given an IP 206.225.92.33, is it possible to redirect myself there while convincing the webserver that I want to be redirected to the appropriate virtualhost?

Comment: Have you tried the [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have IP address on which web site is still working, then you can bypass DNS system by adding record to your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on Unix systems).

Record should look like this:
`<ip.address> <domain.name>`

Like:
`10.0.0.1 example.com`

Your system will first look into hosts file and only if there is no matching record it will do DNS request. So, that can allow you to access virtual hosts which doesn't have DNS records pointed at them.

Comment: I tried that but it just loads the host's website as if I'd only entered the IP.

Comment: @Zhro: Then perhaps the web server no longer hosts that domain, either? If it did, then it wouldn't care – and wouldn't even _know_ – that `http://example.com/` goes through /etc/hosts and not DNS. (I've used this method in the past, successfully.)

Comment: @Zhro As @grawity already said - this most likely means that virtual host you're trying to reach is also turned off. Web servers detect site by `Host` HTTP header. So, if you have `Host` header set correctly in your HTTP requests and server still responds with wrong web page, then you're just getting default virtual host on that IP. `Host` header can be inspected in developer tools depending on browser you are using. For firefox it would be `Developer` -> `Network`.